# How can be count() used to get the number of array entries in document.?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I want to count number of sub document where `type="User.Notice"`. My database is as below.

[image]

i wrote following query but it's returning 1 or 0 always. What's possibly wrong with it.

```
long countss = eventlist.count(new BasicDBObject("192_168_10_17.type", new BasicDBObject("$eq", "User.Notice")));
System.out.println(countss);
```

**Update:**

How can i get all records under particular array. I want all the documents under array `192_168_10_17. can you suggest a way?

Comment: You can not use `192_168_10_17.type` as `192_168_10_17` is an array.

Comment: but this works perfectly fine.`list = eventlist.distinct("192_168_10_17.type")`

Comment: tried this : `long countss = eventlist.count(new BasicDBObject("192_168_10_17.type", "User.Notice"));`

Comment: @dev : it would be returning 1 or 0..

Comment: @Ahbhiji Bashetti: yes you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should unwind `192_168_10_17` and used mongo aggregation as below

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
"$unwind": "$192_168_10_17"
}, {
"$match": {
    "192_168_10_17.type": "User.Notice"
}
}, {
"$group": {
    "_id": "$192_168_10_17.type",
    "count": {
        "$sum": 1
    }
}
}, {
"$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "count": "$count"
}
})
```

Above query return all matching `User.Notice` count. Now convert this query in java using [mongo java aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/) . I tried following java code as below

```
// unwind 192_168_10_17
DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$192_168_10_17");
// create  pipeline operations, with the $match
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match",new BasicDBObject("192_168_10_17.type", "User.Notice"));
// Now the $group operation
 DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", "$192_168_10_17.type");
groupFields.put("count", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
// build the $projection operation
DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("_id", 0);
fields.put("count", "$count");
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", fields);
// run aggregation
List < DBObject > pipeline = Arrays.asList(match, group, project);
 AggregationOutput output = collectionName.aggregate(pipeline);
for (DBObject result: output.results()) {
 System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: can you look at following please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771457/documents-under-array-in-mongodb-java

Comment: @yogesh : I am not able find the method collectionName.aggregate(pipeline) ...? which vesrion of mongo java driver been used?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti check given url in answer `mongo java aggregation`  and   version 2.9.0 of the Java driver, more details here http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/