# How to get array of document using Mongodb java?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java, nosql

How to get all the document under array in mongodb java. My Database is as below. Want to retrieve all the data under array `198_168_1_134`.

[image]

below is some of What i tried,

```
eventlist.find(new BasicDBObject("$match","192_168_10_17"))
eventlist.find(new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch","192_168_10_17"))
eventlist.find(null, new BasicDBObject("$192_168_10_17", 1))
```

Comment: How can we copy and paste code from an image so that we can help you by reproducing the same problem on our PCs?

Comment: @chirdam it's just for reference that how database is look a like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- using `.find()` with cherry-picking which document you have to have fetched.
- using the aggregation framework by projecting the documents.

By using `.find()` , you can do:

```
db.collection.find({}, { 192_168_10_17 : 1 })
```

By using the aggregation framework, you can do:

```
db.collection.aggregate( { $project : { 192_168_10_17 : 1 } } )
```

which will fetch **only** the `192_168_10_17` document data.

Of course, in order to get this working in Java, you have to *translate* these queries to a corresponding chain of `BasicDBObject` instances.

Comment: Should be working. Try it out again. Anyway, I'm glad I helped you. :)\

Answer (score 0):

By using mongo java driver you can do this by following query -

```
eventlist.find(new BasicDBObject(), new BasicDBObject("198_168_1_134", 1))
```